# Case sensitivity on context.request.query properties on Plumier

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, plumier

I have a controller with `appId` parameter like below

```js
@route.root("/applications/:appId/users")
export class ApplicationsUsersController {

    save(@val.mongoId() appId:string, data:User){ 
        // implementation
    }
}
```

Next I have a custom authorization that will access the `request.query.appId` but look like its not there.

```js
function allowOwner(){
    return authorize.custom(async info => {
        const appId = info.ctx.request.query.appId 
        //query.appId not exists but query.appid (lowercase)
    })
}
```

I see that there is a lowercased `appId` but Im not sure if its an expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's a bug!**
Its caused by the Plumier router [merge](https://github.com/plumier/plumier/blob/afbda5ea45ca287b7ff7cc08e9972a6586c44c2a/packages/core/src/router.ts#L70) the result of `path-to-regexp` which the url is lowercase.

For workaround you can access all query in lowercase until Plumier provide a fix.